# Material Design icon width

Tags: css, material-design

How can I reduce the width of the material design icon? There's unnecessary width to the left. I've tried to change the width and font-size properties with no success.

[image]

```
<div>
    <i class="material-icons">ic_autorenew</i>
</div>
```

What can I do so that the icon occupies only the space it needs?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

Changing ic_autorenew to autorenew has solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you for following this up! I have been scratching my head on this for a little while.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code you are using `div` . which itself a `block` element.
Rather you can use `span`. which is a `inline` element.

//example

```
<span class="material-icons">
autorenew
</span>
```

You can check any example  [Here](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=backup&style=baseline)